# Delaying time using SystemcurrentTimeMillis

Tags: loops, methods, time, delay, milliseconds

The code i'm working on deals with a flock of birds moving around fast on the canvas. What I need to do is slow down how fast the birds refresh on the screen by using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method. I need to use it in a while loop so that it waits 20 milliseconds before it makes the birds move around again. I'm not quite sure on how to do this.

Here is the current code:

```
while(NeWorld.isAlive())
{
    NeWorld.updateWorld();
}
```

`NewWorld.isAlive` allows the birds to move around, and the `NeWorld.updateWorld()` refreshes it. It refreshes too fast and I need to slow it down with the `System.currentTimeMillis()` method so that it only refreshes every 20 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `updateWorld()` logic in a separate function, you can call it with certain intervals. Here is an example.

```
boolean iShouldStillUpdateWorld = true;
while (iShouldStillUpdateWorld) {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 20 == 0) {
        updateWorld();
    }
    iShouldStillUpdateWorld = checkIfIShouldUpdateWorld();
}
```

This simply sits in a loop and checks if 20 millis has passed. If so, it calls your `updateWorld()` function then checks if it should continue to repeat this process.

Comment: If `updateWorld()` takes less than 20 milliseconds to run, you'll end up running it again without pausing... Additionally, the way I read the question, you should be waiting 20 milliseconds between the end of one `updateWorld()` and the start of the next, i.e. not just every 20 milliseconds.